# How to numpy.reshape huge data in a HDF5 file without loading all of the data into memory at once?

Tags: python, numpy, dask, hdf5, h5py

I've a h5 file with ~4GB data. I want to numpy.reshape the data but without loading all of the data into memory at once as it results in a memory error. I use h5py to access the file. Thanks!

Edit: I've found Dask arrays and they're pretty good for this task!

Comment: You'll have to create a new dataset with the desired shape, and copy slices from the source (with any required reshape).

Comment: hpaulj is correct. If a dataset doesn't fit in memory, you will have to work with slices. Question: Why do you want/need to reshape the data? I assume you don't plan to read the entire 4GB of data into memory after you reshape. If so, reshaping may not be necessary if you read data slices you need. Please share before/after reshaped dtype. Maybe there is an simpler approach.

Comment: You're right, I'm only planning to read slices of the data after reshaping. The dtype (float32) isn't changing, and the file is being reshaped from 3D to 4D.